# Roles vs multi auth in laravel

Tags: laravel

I tried multi authentication and some people seem to think it is a bad practice.

1.Which use case requires which implementation?
2.What is the best approach?

Comment: Creating middleware for extra auth's. This should be the best way.

Comment: you should google first then post the question, Hope you will get your answer form here https://laravel-news.com/two-best-roles-permissions-packages

Comment: @er.irfankhan11  my question is !how to implement roles ...its roles vs multi-auth. and yes i did google it.and am not the  first to ask it,but for some reason its never fully answered

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my opinion roles are the best solution because yo only query the users table. Also you can use Laravel Policies and Gates in a better way